# Why isn't my swap stylesheet button working?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in javascript, html, and css. I am creating a website where I'd like to have a stylesheet swap button. I added in the javascript in an external file and linked with </script src="> but it doesn't seem to be swapping stylesheets. Where might I have gone wrong in the process?

HTML:

```
<script src="MainButtons.js"></script>
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('styleOD.css')">
    <h4>Change to "Open Dyslexic"</h4>
</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
  document.getElementbyId('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
```

Comment: For starters open your browser developer tools console and check for errors thrown. Once open also look at the network tab where you can see all resource requests for the page and check `status` for the stylesheet request. Is `styleOD.css` in same directory level as the page you are running this on? There are a wide variety of reasons it may not be working so learning some basic debugging tools and techniques is just as important as learning to write the code. Study some tutorials on using *browser developer tools*

Comment: `getElementById` not `getElementbyId`

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much.